# How to open a folder with a local file manager?

Tags: org-mode

I use Emacs 26.3 on Ubuntu 20.04 and I often need to manipulate org files with Ubuntu file manager. It would save me a lot of time if I could open directories from emacs file links. For example, I would like to be able to open folder PRISM through the following link :
[[./References/Deliverables/PRISM/proposal.org][PRSM Proposal]].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about Ubuntu at the desktop level, but on my Gnome desktop, I can open a directory in the file manager from the command line, using the command `xdg-open /path/to/directory`. I assume there is something similar (or perhaps identical) to `xdg-open` on the Ubuntu desktop.

If so, all you have to do is write a function that parses the link at point, selects the directory part of the path (which may be the whole path, or it may be a prefix of the path, as in your example) and then calls `xdg-open` (or whatever the Ubuntu equivalent is) with that path as argument. Then you bind the function to a key and off you go.

Here's a function that looks at the link at point and calls `xdg-open` with
the directory part of the path of the link.

```el
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
  (defun ndk/desktop-open-link-at-point()
    (interactive)
    (let* ((context
            (org-element-lineage (org-element-context) '(link) t))
           (type (org-element-type context))
           (path (org-element-property :path context))
           (dirpath (if (file-directory-p path)
                       path
                      (file-name-directory path))))
      (shell-command (format "xdg-open %s" dirpath) nil nil)))
#+end_src
```

For convenience, bind the function to the key `<M-S-f12>` (i.e. Meta-Shift-FunctionKey12) or some other undefined key in your keymaps:

```el
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(define-key global-map (kbd "<M-S-f12>") #'ndk/desktop-open-link-at-point)
#+end_src
```

Comment: Thanks a lot NickD, it worked perfectly! And for the record, xdg-open works on Ubuntu. Do you by any chance know how can I list all emacs defined keys, so I can define a key which isn't already defined ?

Comment: See [Keymaps](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Keymaps.html#Keymaps) in the Emacs Lisp doc but be warned: things are not simple. You might want to start with the more introductory sections of the Emacs manual: [Keys](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keys.html#Keys) and [Key Bindings](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Key-Bindings.html#Key-Bindings) before you tackle the first link.

Comment: I found C-h b (describe-bindings) which displays a list of all the key bindings in effect.

Comment: Just realize that whatever is in effect in this buffer is not necessarily the same as what is in effect in the next buffer you visit: it depends on the buffer's major mode and all the minor modes enabled (at least).